# Array does not work in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I tried to make a function that returns an array, the output should be "My name is Sarah Adam" but actually it does not return anything

```
/*global s:true*/
var m = 'My name is ';
function updateMsg(h) {
    "use strict";
    var el = m + h;
    s = ['Adam', 'Joseph'];
    return s;
}
var n1 = document.getElementById("msg");
n1.textContent = updateMsg("Sarah")[0];
```

Comment: you are returning `s` (the array)

Answer (score 3):

you are returning `s` (the array) - I think you want to return the concatenated message. As in:

***Updated to include variable last names***

```js
var m = 'My name is ';

function updateMsg(h, index) {
  "use strict";
  var el = m + h;

  // array of last names
  var s = ['Adam', 'Joseph'];

  return el + ' ' + s[index]; // return the concatenated string instead
}
var n1 = document.getElementById("msg");

n1.textContent = updateMsg("Sarah", 0); // invoke with param

// console log (confirmation)
console.log(updateMsg("Sarah", 0));
console.log(updateMsg("Meenah", 1));
```

```html
<div id="msg">
  hw
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use currying to accomplish this. Just swap your brackets `[0]` for parentheses `(0)`.

```js
var m = 'My name is ';

function updateMsg(h) {
  var s = ['Adam', 'Joseph'];
  return function(index) { // return a function that concatenates when given index
    return m + h + " " + s[index];
  };
}

var messageMaker = updateMsg("Sarah");
console.log(messageMaker(0));
console.log(messageMaker(1));
```

Comment: 'currying' or 'querying' ?

Comment: @ochi It's currying. Here's a small [tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/currying-in-functional-javascript/). It's a concept from functional programming.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to acces one element of the list of lastnames an pass the name. I have corrected your code and do something similar to what you want :

```js
let m = 'My name is ',
  s = ['Adam', 'Joseph'],
  updateMsg = (h, i) => m + h + ' ' + s[i],
  n1 = document.getElementById("msg");
n1.textContent = updateMsg("Sarah", 0);
```

```html
<p id="msg"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Details are in the source in the comments.

#### SNIPPET

```js
/*
Global variable: intro
*/
var intro = 'My name is ';

/*
Paramenter: who
*/
function updateMsg(who) {

  /* 
  Array of 2 Strings: guess 
  Named it guess because that's
  what I ended up doing with it
  */
  var guess = [' Shadey', ' Joseph'];

  /*
  Concated String: `hello`
  Since `intro` is global it's always accessible
  `who` is the parameter with value of "Slim"
  `guess[0]` = 'Shadey'
  */
  var hello = intro + who + guess[0];

  /*
  Output of `updateMsg()` function is `hello`
  which is "My name is Slim Shadey"
  */
  return hello;
}

/*
Reference the `output` element as `noLogic`
*/
var noLogic = document.getElementById("msg");

/*
Set `noLogic's` text to whatever `updateMsg()`
returns
`updateMsg()` parameter is "Slim"
*/
noLogic.textContent = updateMsg("Slim");
```

```html
<output id="msg"></output>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the intent is to return an array with `el` prepended to each of the names in `s`. So you need to loop through the array to create the new array.

```js
var m = 'My name is ';
function updateMsg(h) {
  "use strict";
  var el = m + h;
  var s = ['Adam', 'Joseph'];
  return s.map(function(name) {
    return el + ' ' + name;
  });
}
var n1 = document.getElementById("msg");
n1.textContent = updateMsg("Sarah")[0];
```

```html
<div id="msg">
</div>
```